# Does Teradata 14 support bitwise?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, teradata

I can swear that I heard that TD14 will support bitwise, but I see no mention of it in searches nor searching "bitwise" in the TD14 manual.

Can someone confirm whether or not bitwise is supported?

BTW, the manual I am looking at is the Teradata User Documentation in case there's another doc that I should be reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Chapter 4 of the Teradata 14 SQL Functions, Operators, Expressions and Predicates manual explains the Byte/Bit Manipulation Functions available in Teradata 14 via embedded services functions.

(**read:** They are not native ANSI operators like what is found in Transact-SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Teradata 14 (and other versions) support these kinds of functions, as documented in Chapter 6, "Bit/Byte Manipulation Functions," of the "SQL Functions, Operators, Expressions, and Predicates" reference.  Specifically, they have `BITAND(target_arg, bit_mask_arg)`, as well as BITNOT, BITOR, BITXOR, COUNTSET, GETBIT, SETBIT, ROTATELEFT, ROTATERIGHT, SHIFTLEFT, SHIFTRIGHT, and SUBBITSTR.